# Converting ndarray from float32 to uint8 messes the image up

Tags: python, numpy

Following [this blog](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/5.4-visualizing-what-convnets-learn.ipynb) I am trying to apply heatmap to the original image.

However I have a problem converting float32 to uint8. Before converting to uint8 if I save the image with:

```
plt.imshow(heatmap)
plt.savefig(f'{directory}/heatmap.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.0)
```

will output this image:

[image]

After the line `heatmap = np.uint8(255 * heatmap)`I save the image again and get the following output:

[image]

The shape of image in both cases is `(600, 600)`. So how can I get 2nd image to be the same as 1st after using uint8?

Comment: When I try it, everything works fine. Can you post the full code you used?

Comment: Funnily, after your comment I tried it on np.random.rand(32, 32) and the it worked ok. However I dumped my ndarray into .npy file where I get the same results. Link:https://ufile.io/gq308"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only negative values in `heatmap`. Since `uint8` can only hold numbers between `0` and `255` the line `heatmap = np.uint8(255 * heatmap)` will only work as intended if the original values of `heatmap` are lying between `0.` and `1.`.

Solution:
Rescale the array to the range of `[0,255]` before casting it to `uint8`:

```
heatmap = np.uint8(np.interp(heatmap, (heatmap.min(), heatmap.max()), (0, 255)))
```